# Flex не корректно работает в IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

В проекте использую `display: flex;`. Во всех браузерах все ОК, кроме IE 11.

Вот код:

```css
.container-wrap,
.container-wrap>article {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0;
  flex: 0;
}

.news {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrap row-flex-wrap">
  <article class="news">
    <div class="news-wrap">
      <div class="news-heading">
        <a href="#" class="news-rubric">Россия</a> - <span class="news-date">2 июля 2014</span>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/preview1.jpg" alt="" />
        <h3>Факультет неугодных людей</h3>
        <p>Что стоит за кадровыми перестановками на социологическом факультете МГУ</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="news">
    <div class="news-wrap">
      <div class="news-heading">
        <a href="#" class="news-rubric">ЧМ-2014</a> - <span class="news-date">2 июля 2014</span>
      </div>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="img/preview2.jpg" alt="" />
        <h3>Статистика - дело тонкое</h3>
        <p>Занимательные цифры чемпионата мира по футболу в Бразилии</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

В IE 11 все выглядит так:
[image: IE 11 flex]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте прописать для news:

```
.news {
 flex: 0 0 50%; 
 width: 50%;
}
```

И чтобы работал wrap, пропишите для .row-flex-wrap:

```
.row-flex-wrap {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Вендорными префиксами посыпте по вкусу. И лучше это делать автоматически каким нибудь автопрефиксером, а то такой css читать сложновато.

Comment: это gulp так компилирует. спасибо, помогло)